# How do I write to files that are inside of files which the script is not in?

Tags: python

I need to figure out how to fix this code:

```
path = "/Folder/Test.txt"
with open(path,"r+") as f:
    line = f.readline()
print(line)
```

It needs to be able to write to the text document "Test.txt" in the folder named "Folder"

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: What is the code doing that isn't correct? Is it giving an error?

Comment: I wouldn't use path as a variable name, easy to confuse with `os.path`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your path should be relative:

```
path = "./Folder/Test.txt"
```

if you want to write to a file you need `"w"` instead of `"r"` in the open function

Read:

```
with open(path, "r") as f:
    line = f.readline()
print(line)
```

Write:

```
with open(path, "w") as f:
    f.write("Hello world!")
```

Using `"w"` will replace all the current content of the file. If you want to append to the file instead, you should use `"a"`.

Comment: The mode the OP used is fine. `"r+"` allows reading and writing of the file.

Answer (score -1):

`path` should be in `/absolute/location/of/file/filename`.

That means either `"C:/file/path/you/want/filename"` in Windows or `"/absolute/path/of/your/file/filename"` in *nix
You can also use relative paths if the path you want is nearby (shares a directory, etc.)

For example: if the script is in `/user/scripts` and you want to save in `/user/textfiles/Folder`, you can do `../textfiles/Folder`

Also make sure that the folder exists, else, it will cause an error as well.

Anyway, as you go further in python, it is recommended that you check out the [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module as it can help you a lot with file paths and other things

Comment: You did not answer his question.. He asked how to write to a file.